# Any way without js to ensure floated divs in same 'row' are the same height without setting height attr

Tags: javascript, css

I would like to float a set of divs to make a fluid layout. And I would love to do it with pure CSS and no js if possible for performance/complexity reasons.

Currently, we have 3 divs per row and the surrounding element stretches vertically to accommodate the the tallest div. But of course when I make the page narrower or wider, I always have 3 divs per row.

With floated divs that *don't* have row containers, it looks great as long as all the divs have the same height. But if the 2nd div in a 2-div row is shorter than the first, then the next row's 1st div gets 'stuck' to the right of that 1st taller div, leaving the first spot in the 2nd row empty.

A solution might be to bring back row divs and use javascript to shuffle item divs between them, but that might be complicated and error-prone. But maybe that's the only possibility.

The one thing I can't do is use fixed height for the item divs, because that would require setting the fixed height large enough for the largest possible item div, which would leave a bunch of empty space for every other div.

I guess another possibility might be using fixed height, then use js to adjust those heights to eliminate extra space.

Comment: You should look into flexbox.

Comment: easiest would be to use "dispaly:table-cell"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make the `display:inline-block` and remove the float. Height will become optional as well, they'd just align to the tallest one.

Comment: This is almost working perfectly, but the item divs are aligning at their bottoms. I need their tops to align. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: I knew it would be something obvious.

Comment: You're welcome :D You could also accept the answer if everything is working now.

Comment: Ahh yes, I meant to accept as well. Great answer. Welcome to stackoverflow, by the way.

Answer (score 2):

If possible try switching to flexbox. https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox has great visuals to illustrate how various flex styles work.

For example, you could use `flex-wrap: wrap;` to handle the case when the page becomes too narrow, and use `align-items: stretch` so they all have the same height

Comment: This looks interesting. I've never heard of this before. I read a bit about it after I saw your answer, but I'm not sure if it would solve the row-of-2 vs row-of-3 problem as well as Lucian Davidescu's answer (which uses `display:inline-block;vertical-align:top`) anyway.